# HTML table td display

Tags: html, html-table

I have multiple HTML tables which has some Ruby code embedded in it. It looks like below :

```
<% loop-1 %>
<table>
   <tr>
     <td rowspan=" X ">abcd</td>
     <td>xyz</td>
    </tr>

    <% loop-2 %>
    <% if (condition) %>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>xyz1</td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
 </table>  
<% end %>
```

So as seen above, there are multiple tables generated based on loop-1. Now each table will have atleast one row. After the first row, there is again another loop-2 and some condition. There might be variable number of rows after the first row for each table. I want the first  of the first  to have the rowspan(X) = no. of total rows for that table.

For example. if after the first row, loop-2 generates 2 more rows, I want the X=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using only HTML. The only possible way is to count how many occurrence of condition will take place *befroe* your loop. I.e. executing the same loop earlier and increment X each time condition met.